# Перелистывание книги на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли реаоизовать на JS перелистывание книги? Образец: http://wobook.com/infos/WBvM1HB5Mp4r-wb/Revista-LastZone-EDICION-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Выбирайте любой](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/)

Answer (score 2):

[Оно](http://www.turnjs.com/)?